# MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to a remote server

Tags: mysql

I want to import a csv file from my local computer to a mysql server on a remote machine using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. When I try this without `LOCAL` and my file is stored at the remote computer it works (file and mysql on the same server), but is not working when the mysql server is on a remote computer.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/wamp/www/accesos/uploaded_files/wawawa.csv'
INTO TABLE eventos
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@skip,@skip,@skip,@skip,@skip,@skip,@skip,@skip,@skip,nombre,@skip,num_servo,@fecha,hora,@skip,num_tarjeta,@archivo_procedencia)
set archivo_procedencia = 'test_file', fecha = STR_TO_DATE(@fecha, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

So, what I'm doing from my computer: I'm connecting to phpmyadmin on the remote computer.
Executing the above code but is not working. But it works if I remove `"LOCAL"` and move my file to the remote computer and change the path to match the file path.

The error is:

Can't find file 'C:/wamp/www/accesos/uploaded_files/wawawa.csv'.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: first question, does the file exist and does MySQL have the read rights to that file?

Comment: File does exist on the local computer, the file is being send to the remote computer when using this statement right? I don't think this would be a permission issue, I can import the same file from the gui utility on phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From documentation:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

> The LOCAL keyword affects expected location of the file and error handling, as described later. LOCAL works only if your server and your client both have been configured to permit it. For example, if [**mysqld**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld.html) was started with [`--local-infile=0`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile), LOCAL does not work. See Section 6.1.6, [“Security Issues with LOAD DATA LOCAL”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data-local.html).
>
> The LOCAL keyword affects where the file is expected to be found:
>
> - If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the client host and sent to the server. The file can be given as a full path name to specify its exact location.

In Your case client program is *phpmyadmin*. So it expects csv file is on server where *phpmyadmin* is installed. To work with files on your local computer, you must use MySQL client program installed locally on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

The `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement loads a file on machine the MySQL server is running on. (the remote server)

Use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to load a file located on your local machine.